# Help with Multi Level Category Archive Page

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, categories, theme-development, custom-post-type-archives

I'm currently building a site for a local beauty salon and I have come across an issue that I just cannot seem to put my finger on and I have been stuck on this for weeks, where I'm stuck is with the treatments page.

The project requires that I have a treatments page that lists all available treatment categories (massage, waxing, nails, etc). When a user clicks on the treatment category they're after they are then taken to another page that lists all the treatments within that category i.e., Treatments -> Waxing -> Full Leg Wax.

I did a Google search to try and find a good example of what I'm after and I came up with [this example](http://www.germaine-de-capuccini.com.au/category/treatments/) and it is exactly what I'm after.

#### Hierarchy

- List of Treatment Categories (URL: site.com/treatments)

  - Individual Treatments (URL: site.com/treatments/waxing)

    - Individual Treatment Details (URL: site.com/treatments/waxing/back-wax)

I have used a custom post type for the individual treatments, named 'treatments', and then I created a taxonomy called ‘treatment-categories’ (I’ve used the slug names of each). I have used my archive.php template and obviously I have named this archive-treatments.php (code below). I will look at altering the layout of the template once I have this figured out.

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<section class="hero hero-sml hero-default no-marg-bottom">
    <div class="container clearfix">
        <h1>
            <?php
                the_archive_title( '<h1>', '</h1>' );
            ?>
        </h1>
    </div><!-- .container -->
</section><!-- .hero -->

<div class="muted-bg">
    <section class="margin-top container clearfix">
        <div class="row">

            <?php if( have_posts() ) : while( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

            <div class="col-4 post-excerpt">
               <article>

                   <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                       <?php
                           // Display the featured image
                           if( the_post_thumbnail() ) :
                       the_post_thumbnail( 'small' );
                    endif;
                 ?>
              </a>

              <time class="post-date">
                 <?php the_date(); ?>
              </time>

              <h3>
                 <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                    <?php the_title(); ?>
                 </a>
              </h3>

              <p>
                 <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
              </p>

           </article>
        </div><!-- .post-excerpt -->

     <?php endwhile; endif; ?>

  </div><!-- .row -->
```

I have done the same for the treatment-categories taxonomy (archive-treatment-categories), is this the correct way of doing this? Is WordPress even capable of doing something like this? Also just to clarify in case this maybe an issue, I have a blog that utilises categories, tags, etc and a WooCommerce store if that helps.

I really appreciate any help with this, and I'm sure it's one of those solutions where I'll be saying "really, is that all I had to do?". I have been trying this for way too long and it doesn't make any sense anymore to me, I just need another opinion on how to do this.

Thanking you all in advance

Stu :)

Comment: At first glance it looks like your template should list all of the posts within the category that you are trying to access.  Is that not what you want?

Comment: Hi Andy. Here's what currently happens. When I go to the treatment page I can see all of the individual treatments list (URL: site.com/treatments) but there is no treatment categories (Waxing, Massage, etc) and it's going to the archive-treatments.php. Should I be utilizing a taxonomy or category template? Here's the URL I see site.com/treatments/half-leg-wax but it should be site.com/treatments/waxing/half-leg-wax/ Bit of a newbie with WordPress and I'm still trying to get my head around everything

Comment: To get your URLs like that, make sure your taxonomy is hierarchical and then set the parent of half-leg-wax to be treatments. As for showing them on the page, you'll need code for that in your template. I'll have a look at a proper answer with code when I'm back at a computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been successful in achieving exactly what I was looking for. For me to solve this dilemma I used the following code in the archive-treatments template using the following code:

```
<?php
    $args = array( 'taxonomy' => 'treatment-categories' );
    $categories = wp_list_categories( $args);
?>
```